# When did wordpress switched requirements to php7?

Tags: php, wordpress.org

I cannot find this information anywhere. Does any of you knows when exactly (from what version on) they switched system requirements to PHP 7?

EDIT

https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/

When did wordpress start recommending php7? From what of the wordpress versions? Or what date (more difficult, and I don't strictly need).

Comment: It didn't, but perhaps you have Yoast SEO installed? I would **strongly** recommend updating your PHP version to at least 5.6/7.0 to fix security issues, and gain ***huuuuuge*** speed improvements

Comment: This looks like a post from the far future - I will bookmark it and revisit it in 20+ years ;-)

Comment: I edited my question to help understanding what I mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [currently **required**](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) minimal PHP version is still **5.2.4+**.

The **recommended** version is 7. [According to archive.org](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20161203082901/https://wordpress.org/about/requirements) since December 2, 2016.

Note that many plugins and themes need at least PHP 5.4 or newer nowadays, and that PHP versions below 5.6 [do not get security updates anymore](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) and are therefore probably not safe for production.

WordPress doesn't use any of the newer PHP features, but it does work with the latest PHP version.

Comment: These are right informations but don't answer to my question. From what WP version did they officially start recommending php7?

Comment: @Stratboy These recommendations are not bound to any WordPress version. Andrew Nacin makes updates on that page whenever he thinks it's the right time.

Comment: @Stratboy I made an update and included the date.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your question properly but to answer properly now. WordPress introduced Php 7 in late November 2015. It was previously coming from Php 5

Comment: this is not a perfect answer, but my question probably wasn't clear. I edited it so maybe you can give me the right info.